# Adding tags to jekyll post breaks page

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

Let's say i have the following front matter:

```
title: example
date: 2019-09-16 00:00:00+2000
layout: post
categories: blog
```

And the following HTML code:

```html
{% for post in site.posts %}
    {% for tag in post.tags %}
        <input type="checkbox">{{tag}}<br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

As expected the page looks like it should and the code looks like what you would expect:

> How it should look:
>
> [image: Correct display]
>   [image: Correct code]

But, if i add the following front matter:

```
tags: ["code", "test", "example", "python"]
```

Everything breaks:

> WRONG
>
> [image: Broken display (Top)]
>   [image: Broken code]

What is happening?

`jekyll -v` >> `jekyll 4.0.0`

Gems:

- Rouge (Code formatting)
- Jekyll SEO tag (SEO from _config.yml)
- Jekyll sitemap (Generates a sitemap.xml file)
- Jeyll feed (Generates an RSS feed)

EDIT: Seems it grabs the entire post and not just the category if i add this:

```
{% for category in site.categories %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{category}}" value="{{category | capitalize }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Which is clearly wrong

Comment: This is strange. Are you using any plugins? What version of Jekyll are you using?

Comment: @ashmaroli see edited post

Comment: Is the source code publicly available like on GitHub, etc? I'd like to take a look at it..

Comment: @ashmaroli yea, [here](https://gitlab.com/TacoCraftxD/taco-blog/tree/preparation-redesign). Make sure to use the `preparation-redesign` branch

Comment: @ashmaroli see the most recent commit and edit of post

Comment: Both `site.tags` and `site.categories` are *hashes* of key-value pairs and are pre-defined entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is because of the following code in your site's `meta`:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="{{site.tags}}">
```

`site.tags` is a *hash* of all posts tagged to a given string.
A *hash* here denotes a container of key-value pairs. For example:

```
{"foo" => "bar", "alpha" => "beta"}
```

---

---

### Solutions

Use some other variable to denote the keywords. For example, `keywords`.
In your config file, replace the key `tags` with `keywords`.

```
keywords: [
  "HTML",
  "Python",
  "CSS",
  "Coding",
  "Blog"
]
```

Then update your `head.html` include:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="{{ site.keywords }}">
```

---

Regarding the rendering of checkboxes, you need to know that kramdown considers all lines with 4 leading spaces to denote a code-block.
Therefore the following

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
    {% for tag in post.tags %}
        <input type="checkbox">{{tag}}<br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

will only produce

```
    <input type="checkbox">code<br>

    <input type="checkbox">test<br>

    <input type="checkbox">example<br>

    <input type="checkbox">python<br>
```

(They're not rendered as HTML inputs but as raw code.)

---

To see the internal representation of any object you intend to use in Liquid, you can pass it to the `inspect` filter. For example, to see what `site.tags` (or `site.categories` even) are actually, you could inspect them via:

```
<pre>{{ site.tags | inspect }}</pre>
```